# Strange error since upgrading to Android 4.2.2 - Activity has leaked IntentReceiver

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks

I upgraded my Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 to Android 4.2.2 last night, and have since spotted some strange errors in `LogCat` which didn't appear before I 'upgraded'.

I was hoping that it was highlighting a hidden bug or memory leak in my application, but I can't find anything.

It seems to only occur if the activity I'm on has a `Spinner`, and that `Spinner` is expanded.

The error is as below.

`Activity uk.co.xxxx.xxxx has leaked IntentReceiver com.immersion.android.haptics.HapticFeedbackManager$HapticFeedbackBroadcastReceiver@41e4bac0 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?`

Has anyone else seen this? do you think it's safe to ignore as it's only occurring on one of my devices?

--- Edit ---

And, incidentally, I'm not registering any receivers anywhere, so there's nothing to unregister.

Comment: I just upgraded today and am seeing the same error. No receivers registered here either.

Comment: @celoftis Does yours involve a spinner control also?

Comment: Nope, no spinners in the activity where I'm expereiencing this...

Comment: so nobody know what is happen here? the same exeption...

Comment: Same here on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 10.1 inch running Android 4.2.2. In my situation, I just open an app (any app) and rotate the device a few times, then I got the error. Could it have anything to do with the screen rotation class?

Comment: Also, I noticed that the class `com.immersion.android.haptics.HapticFeedbackManager` is not part of the Android Open Source Project SDK, so this class is from a third party. You'll see this class used in a lot of games. Ignoring it? Yes, for the time being. Or, log a bug at **www.immersion.com** and let them fix it.

Comment: This appears to be a Samsung issue. Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7" running Android 4.2.2

Comment: In my case, Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7" running Android 4.2.2, when exiting my app.

Comment: I am receiving the same error. I am also running a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7" which happens when I exit the app. Is there any work around?

Comment: I am also face same issue in Samsung Galaxy Tab 2.

Answer (score 9):

I have the similar problem and I've asked this question on the Haptic developer's forum and received the following reply:

> The exception you see is a harmless warning and the OS will take care
>   of freeing the resources mentioned in the exception. In other words,
>   no need to worry or do anything about it.

If you need any other details - [go here](http://www2.immersion.com/developers/index.php?option=com_kunena&func=view&catid=7&id=653&Itemid=846#658)

Comment: Those are not exactly comforting words.  Leaks are easily detected and cleaned up at shutdown, but until then, they can accumulate over time, sucking up resources.  It can actually even be a security risk, if it can be made a target of a denial of service attack (repeatedly invoking whatever causes the leak).  This is yet another example of the poor coding on the part of those that make Samsung's software/firmware.

Answer (score 0):

From the stack trace I would say your Activity (masked here) registered a `HapticFeedbackBroadcastReceiver` that wasn't properly released. This is typically done in the `onPause()` lifecycle hook so that this gets called when you pause or close the `Activity`.

Example code:

```
@Override 
protected void onPause() {

    super.onPause();
    if(broadcastReceiverInstance != null){
        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiverInstance);
    }
}
```

**If you haven't registered any receivers yourself** maybe the system has based on a keyboard that pops up so it could be a good idea to hide keyboards or any other element used within your app that might have haptic feedback activated. Think of custom keyboards, custom views, ... anything. To check that in more detail we would need more code.