# Missing a call to unregister HapticFeedbackBroadcastReceiver receiver that I never registered

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I get the following error

> "Are you missing a call to unregister receiver"

when I hit the back button to exit my application. How do I identify which Receiver is causing the leak and eliminate the error? I am using the code "DownLoader" from Google to download  an expansion file.

```
10-27 22:13:32.818: E/ActivityThread(30744): Activity com.ssowens.groovebasstrial.BassActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.immersion.android.haptics.HapticFeedbackManager$HapticFeedbackBroadcastReceiver@41d166d0 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
10-27 22:13:32.818: E/ActivityThread(30744): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.ssowens.groovebasstrial.BassActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.immersion.android.haptics.HapticFeedbackManager$HapticFeedbackBroadcastReceiver@41d166d0 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
10-27 22:13:32.818: E/ActivityThread(30744):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:800)
10-27 22:13:32.818: E/ActivityThread(30744):    at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:601)
10-27 22:13:32.818: E/ActivityThread(30744):    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1650)
10-27 22:13:32.818: E/ActivityThread(30744):    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1630)
10-27 22:13:32.818: E/ActivityThread(30744):    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1624)
10-27 22:13:32.818: E/ActivityThread(30744):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:430)
10-27 22:13:32.818: E/ActivityThread(30744):    at com.immersion.android.haptics.HapticFeedbackManager.setupPackageBroadcastReceiver(HapticFeedbackManager.java:564)
10-27 22:13:32.818: E/ActivityThread(30744):    at com.immersion.android.haptics.HapticFeedbackManager.<init>(HapticFeedbackManager.java:108)
10-27 22:13:32.818: E/ActivityThread(30744):    at com.immersion.android.HapticFeedbackManagerProxy.initialize(HapticFeedbackManagerProxy.java:90)
10-27 22:13:32.818: E/ActivityThread(30744):    at com.immersion.android.HapticFeedbackManagerProxy.access$100(HapticFeedbackManagerProxy.java:30)
10-27 22:13:32.818: E/ActivityThread(30744):    at com.immersion.android.HapticFeedbackManagerProxy$1$1.run(HapticFeedbackManagerProxy.java:71)
10-27 22:13:32.818: E/ActivityThread(30744):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange error since upgrading to Android 4.2.2 - Activity has leaked IntentReceiver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18324791/strange-error-since-upgrading-to-android-4-2-2-activity-has-leaked-intentrecei)

Answer (score 10):

**Solution 1.**

If You have a ListView with a ItemClickListener You have to set the listener to null on overrive Method onPause.

listView.setOnItemClickListener(exampleListener);

Example: Declaration of your listener

```
private OnItemClickListener exampleListener = new OnItemClickListener() {}....

@Override
    public void onPause() {

        super.onPause();

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(null);

    }

@Override
    public void onResume() {

        super.onResume();
            if(listView != null){
                listView.setOnItemClickListener(exampleListener);
             }
    }
```

**Solution 2**
If You know what is your broadcastReceiver instance You have to unregister always un overrive method onPause.

@Override
    protected void onPause() {

```
    super.onPause();
    synchronized (this) {
        if(broadcastReceiverInstance != null){
            unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiverInstance );
        }
    }

}
```

The second solution I know it does not work for you but I let it for reference.

I hope it helps You.

Comment: Thank you for your response to my question. However, see the comments above. Looks like my problem is specific to my version (4.2.2) of Android and the tablet (Samsung 7 inch) that I am using. @Schwertfisch

Comment: @sowens I think your problem is with a ListView. if You have one the problem is thath you are not setting your listview listener override onPause. Sorry for my bad english. I'm going to edit the Answer. 
Tell me if does it works.

Comment: A tweak to @Schwertfisch 's approach - in the code I'm working on, the `onItemClickListener(...)` is called in `onCreate()` and a new object instantiated. This would be discarded and replaced in the proposed `onResume()`. So I've added the following guard code to test whether the `onItemClickListener` is null:   `@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (drawerList != null drawerList.getOnItemClickListener() == null) {
            drawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
        }
    }`

Comment: @JulianHarty, is it necessary to call it in both OnCreate and OnResume? OnResume is also called after OnCreate, so having it there would be enough I suppose.

Comment: @roberth I agree that in principle calling it in `OnResume` should be enough. In my case I've been working with someone else's code and didn't want to make major modifications to it so left the code in the `OnCreate` essentially unchanged.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a work around !!       I have a Samsung tab 7" 4.2.2

Causes of problem:
 1. 4.2.2
 2. ListView defined in a Layout.xml
 3. new ListView(this)

Fix:
 1. do not declare a ListView in the Layout, instead declare a holder
 2. use 'getApplication()' instead of 'this'    'new ListView(getApplication());'
 3. addView(yourListView)

TheLayoutFile.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/listViewHolder"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </RelativeLayout>
```

The ListView in your Activity

```
private void displayPostsInListView() {
    RelativeLayout listViewHolder = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.listViewHolder);
    listView = new ListView(getApplication());
    listViewHolder.addView(listView);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(lineItemListener);

    adapter = new MyDisplayAdapter(this, listModel.getPostings());

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: You don't have to create a holder. It's simpler to just nullify the adapter in onStop() and reset as needed

Answer (score 1):

You must call unregisterReceiver() on any receivers you have registered in your Activity. This will typically be in onPause().

Answer (score 1):

> How do I identify which Receiver is causing the leak and eliminate the error?

The answer is in the LogCat you posted.

```
Activity com.ssowens.groovebasstrial.BassActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.immersion.android.haptics.HapticFeedbackManager$HapticFeedbackBroadcastReceiver@41d166d0 that was originally registered here.
```

You registered a `HapticFeedbackBroadcastReceiver` in `BassActivity`, which needs to be unregistered when you pause or close the app. As @svenoaks says, you should override `Activity.onPause()` and unregister every receiver you've registered, using `unregisterReceiver(referenceToReceiver);`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. @Ole However, I have searched for HapticFeedbackBroadcastReceiver in my code and I don't find a match. I am assuming it is when I use the onTouchListener. So, to unregister it would I unregister the onTouchListener? Not sure how to unregister it.

Comment: @sowens Are you testing your application on a Samsung device running 4.2.2?
According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18324791/strange-error-since-upgrading-to-android-4-2-2-activity-has-leaked-intentrecei), there seems to be a bug in Samsungs 4.2.2 build

Comment: Yes, I am running a Samsung version 4.2.2. How unfortunate that this error is occurring. I didn't see any work around in the post.

Comment: I'm having the same problem... But since i am also testing on a samsung tab 2 10.1 with android 4.2.2 i think it may be the same here ... Since the problem shows only errors in logcat und does not crash the app i think i will leave it for now.